# Apache + PHP-FPM + chroot results “File not found.” error

Tags: apache, php, chroot

I want to set chroot to the DocumentRoot using PHP-FPM pools' chroot attribute. With the settings below, whatever I do I get only a "File not found." error:

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/example.conf

```
[example]
user = example
group = example
listen = /var/run/php_fpm_example.sock
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chroot = /opt/jail/example/home/example
php_admin_value[open_basedir]=/opt/jail/example/home/example
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.domain.name
ServerAlias www.example.domain.name
DocumentRoot /opt/jail/example/home/example
<Directory /opt/jail/example/home/example>
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
<FilesMatch \.`enter code here`php$>
SetHandler php-script
</FilesMatch>
Action php-script /php5-fpm-handler
Alias /php5-fpm-handler /vhost_example
FastCGIExternalServer /vhost_example -socket /var/run/php_fpm_example.sock
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

So the website itself is located in /opt/jail/example/home/example. You may find it strange, but doesn't really matter, it is caused by jailkit.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a working version without the chroot in php-fpm?

You should start by that.

Then as soon as you define a chroot in the pool:

```
chroot = /opt/jail/example/home/example
```

You will have to remove this path from other settings ein this pool:

- `listen`
- `chdir`
- php settings, like `php_admin_value[open_basedir]` or `php_value[include_path]` or `php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir]` and all settings working with tmp directory.

Some others seems to ignore the chroot like `slowlog`.

So you have a `listen = /var/run/php_fpm_example.sock`, it means `/opt/jail/example/home/example/var/run/php_fpm_example.sock` and this should be the path for apache `FastCGIExternalServer`.

Configuration of Apache with a chrooted php-fpm and FastCGIExternalServer is quite hard, I [once described it](http://regilero.github.io/Drupal/English/2011/09/03/Install_drupal_in_php_fpm_fastcgi_and_apache_chroot/) with  a fake full directory path symlink inside the chroot (ugly), but with the new **Apache 2.4** you should try to use [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) instead or replace Apache by Nginx.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time trying to get around the symlink inside the chroot in 2.4.10, but to no avail.  mod_proxy_fcgi is not working with UDS (best I can tell), so that seems to still be the only way to make those parts work together (php-fpm, chroot, UDS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use doc_root php.ini directive to avoid symbolic link in your chroot dir.
In your case add this directive in php-fpm conf file (/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/example.conf):

```
php_admin_value[doc_root] = /
```